# How can I efficiently pull a significant number of records from IndexedDb knowing their keys?

Tags: database, performance, google-chrome, query-optimization, indexeddb

So my trouble is that I have a collection of keys of certain records that I keep in my IndexedDb in the Chrome browser, the size of the store (aka table) is near 200 000, the set of keys is about 5 000.

There is no way to use indices, because the keys are very random.

What would be the fastest way to pull these 5000 records corresponding to the keys I have?

My current solution is to cursor through all records in the DB and check if each key is in the set. It's starting to be noticeably slow.

Answer (score 0):

> My current solution is to cursor through all records in the DB and check if each key is in the set. It's starting to be noticeably slow.

Rather than reading every record, read only the ones with matching keys (assuming by "key" you mean the key of the object store):

```
const sortedKeys = [1, 2, 3];
const output = [];
const range = IDBKeyRange.bound(sortedKeys[0], sortedKeys[sortedKeys.length - 1]);
let i = 0;
const request = objectStore.openCursor(range);
request.onsuccess = (event) => {
    const cursor = event.target.result;

    if (!cursor) {
        console.log(output);
        return;
    }

    output.push(cursor.value);
    i += 1;

    cursor.continue(sortedKeys[i]);
};
```